# How to specify the polygon in which to generate points when using the Kenv.csr() function in R?

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics

I would like to use the `Kenv.csr()` function, out of the `splancs` package, which  *computes envelope of Khat from simulations of complete spatial randomness*. My main issue is with one of the parameters: `poly`. It sets the *polygon in which to generate the points*.

I do not understand which format is accepted by that parameter. When I ran the code example which comes with the help documentation, the polygon is actually an area defined by a number of adjacent points. I would like to use a polygon shapefile (SpatialPolygonDataFrame) that I have at my disposal.

Is there a way to convert/reshape the polygon I have to a format that can be fed into the `Kenv.csr()` function?

Answer (score 2):

The polygon argument has to be a 2-column matrix forming a single ring. Shapefiles can be a lot more complex, including multiple features, islands, holes and so on.

`splancs` was written round about the same time shapefiles were invented, and so there was no support for complex geometries.

You might have better luck using `spatstat` for K function envelopes, I am pretty sure it handles windows with holes, and does more edge corrections, and is generally wonderful. Its what I use, and I wrote (most of) `splancs`.

I think there may also be guides for converting shapefile geometries from `sp` objects to the `Window` format that `spatstat` uses. When you get stuck ask again here.